# Rails Cancan NameError - uninitialized constan

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancancan

**Hi, 
I need your help with cancan.**

I have this controler:

**class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController**

I needed because I had to overwrite some methods.

I need to control the access to this controller because the administrator is the only that can add a new user.

How can I use load_and_authorize_resource?

**My ability.rb file is:**
**class Ability**
  include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user, controller_namespace)
     user ||= Usuario.new

```
case controller_namespace
  when "Administrator"
    if user.rol == 1    
        can :manage, Faq
        can :manage, Tip
        can :manage, Administrator::HomeTratamientoController
   end
    if user.rol == 2
        can :manage, :admin_vacunas
        can :manage, Registration
    end
  when "paciente"
    if user.rol == 3
        can :manage, Paciente::HomeController
    end
  else  
        can :read, :all
 end
```

**end**

**The model is usuario.rb**

I don't have problem when the rol is 1 but when is 2, and I put the line:

**load_and_authorize_resource**

when in the registration controller I call the action new to add a new user by the adminstrator, show me the follow error:

**Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 42ms (ActiveRecord: 5.1ms)**

NameError - uninitialized constant Registration:
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:533:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in`const_missing'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in`constantize'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
  cancancan (2.0.0) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:156:in`resource_class'
  cancancan (2.0.0) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:192:in `resource_base'
  cancancan (2.0.0) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:80:in`build_resource'
  cancancan (2.0.0) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:61:in `load_resource_instance'
  cancancan (2.0.0) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:35:in`load_resource'
  cancancan (2.0.0) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:12:in `block in add_before_action'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in`block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in`block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in`_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in`process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in`block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in`instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in`process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in`process'
  actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in`dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in`block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in`serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in`block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in`call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:30:in`traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:32:in`traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:48:in`traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in`call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in`call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in`call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in`call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in`call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in`block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in`_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in`call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in`call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in`protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in`call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in`block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in`call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in`call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.16.1.320) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:96:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in`call'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in`pre_process'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in`receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.2.0.1) lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in`start'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in`run'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in`start'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`server'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`'
  bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (1.7.2) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`call'
  spring (1.7.2) lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
  spring (1.7.2) lib/spring/client.rb:30:in`run'
  spring (1.7.2) bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (1.7.2) lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in`'
  bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:3:in`'

**Some body can help me please?**

Comment: do you actually have a `Registration` model?

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  THe model is Usuario.rb,  RegistrationsController  is a controller from devise, I had read that if I use   in ability.rb file: 
can :manage, Administrator::RegistrationsController 
and in the controller:
load_and_authorize_resource class: "RegistrationsController" should work, but not

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `can :manage, Registration`, so you need a `Registration` model.

In your case you should replace it with:

```
can :create, User
```

and in the controller you `load_and_authorize_resource :user, parent: false`

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions

Free tip:

don't write model names in Spanish, but in English, **always**. So replace `Usuario` with `User`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I really apreciate your help.

Comment: But I need more help.

I put exactly what you indicated, but it shows me an error from exception: You are not authorized to access this page.

I have this in the application_controller:
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, alert: 'You are not authorized to access this page' }
        format.js   { head :forbidden, content_type: 'text/html' }
    end
  end

.The model Usuario.rb is not in the namespace administrator

PD: I know English not spanish, but is a legacy app

Comment: can you print the content of `exception`? Maybe update the question so the formatting is more clear.